# killed error in tensorflow when I try load convolutional pretrained model in jetson tx1

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nvidia

I have a face recognition model trained on a [inception_resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py) Model.

When I run my tensorflow code to load trained model on [Nvidia Jetson TX1](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems-dev-kits-modules/), it just outputs "killed". How do I debug this?

What can I do? I think it's because memory problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the answer!

If you don't set the maximum fraction of GPU memory, it allocates almost the whole free memory. My problem was lack of enough memory for GPU.

You can pass the session configuration.

I set the **per_process_gpu_memory_fraction configuration** in tf.GPUOptions to 0.8 and the problem is solved.

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.8)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installTensorFlowTX2/issues/2) 'killed' on the jetson means it ran out of memory. It may not be possible to run the inception_resnet model on the TX1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reduce the batch_size number, for example from 32 to 16, it will reduce the memory consumption and will increase the training time.

Comment: My question is about inference, not training.